# Ubuntu 18.04: How do I prevent automatic suspend?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, laptop, lenovo

My laptop (Lenovo L520) suspends whenever **I close the lid** even if it's **plugged in**. How can I prevent this? There's no such setting in the power settings (why?). I can find settings for suspend timeouts, but nothing about the lid behavior.

Comment: Don't you want to Suspend your system when laptop lid is closed and when it's on AC power??

Comment: No. I'm using this old laptop as a build server and it's a bit hard if it suspends against my will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start Gnome Tweaks and change this setting...

[image]

In 19.04 you'll also find...

[image]

Comment: Is this a system wide setting or how does that work if no users are logged in?

Comment: My guess would be system wide... but try it and find out... report back here.

Comment: This seemed to be user-specific. I need to log in - otherwise the laptop still suspends.

Comment: @user205301 see the update in my answer.

Comment: This works only for the user who is logged in. It's not system wide.